# Element with set width not wrapping around floated element and dropping

Tags: html, css

By setting the width of the `right-column` it drops below the left floated element `left-column` instead of wrapping around it, even though there is enough space. Why is this happening? From my understanding if there is enough space the right column should reflow around the left floated element?

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
.container {
 width: 400px;
 overflow: hidden;
 background: lightgreen;
}
.left-column {
 width: 200px;
 float: left;
 background: red;
}
.right-column {
 width: 200px;
 background: cyan;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
 <div class='left-column'>I am the left column</div>
 <div class='right-column'>I am the right column</div>
</div>
```

Why is setting `right-column` to float right or setting `margin-left: 200px` prevent the drop?

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
.container {
 width: 400px;
 overflow: hidden;
 background: lightgreen;
}
.left-column {
 width: 200px;
 float: left;
 background: red;
}
.right-column {
 width: 200px;
 float: right;
 background: cyan;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='left-column'>I am the left column</div>
  <div class='right-column'>I am the right column</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Because those elements are blocked. When you float the right column, right it in-lines them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you float an element, you remove it from the normal flow of the document, then **text and inline elements will wrap around it** - not other block level elements. The floated element and the block level element overlap now, and only the text/inline content in the wrapping block element will wrap around the floated element.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float

> The float CSS property specifies that an element should be taken from the normal flow and placed along the left or right side of its container, where text and inline elements will wrap around it.

In your code, the block level element `.right-column` doesn't wrap around the left column - but the text/content inside of it will, except you've given the elements the same width. The left and right divs are overlapping now, but since they're set to the same width, they're sitting on top of one another and the text in the right column has nowhere to go but below the left column. That text is technically wrapping around the left column, but because of the width restriction, it has nowhere to wrap but below the left column. You can see this by extending the width of `.right-column` a little bit. You'll see that `.right-column` now has enough room for some of it's text content to display beside the left column and wrap.

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
.container {
 width: 400px;
 overflow: hidden;
 background: lightgreen;
}
.left-column {
 width: 200px;
 float: left;
 background: red;
}
.right-column {
 width: 300px;
 background: cyan;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='left-column'>I am the left column</div>
  <div class='right-column'>I am the right column</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks! I was starting to think in the same direction of the answer you provided.

Comment: @RobertRocha np! It isn't the most intuitive concept. I worked with floats for years before I really understood their behavior.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

> **Why float not working with right `div`**

**Short Ans:**

> You haven't write floating position for `.right-column`.

**Long Ans**

Initial `div` is `block` label element. Default `direction: ltr;`. If you set only `width` for the `.left-column` and `.right-column` it will default set the `left` direction. Your first snippet set only `float: left;` for `.left-column` it doesn't changed `.right-colun` direction even if you have enough space on right side. That reason your first snippet `.right-column` isn't set in right direction`. You should change the direction for every column.

`CSS` `float` property isn't change actual `direction` property it change `box-modle` position for every element.

> Note: Without floating element box-model controlled by parent element **direction** property.
>
> Direction property default set by browser engine `ltr` for the language. When you try to develop **Hebrew** and **Arabic** language website this time you should change the body direction left to right that means `ltr` to `rtl` and floating should be start from right `(float: right;)` for every element.

**Lets play with direction property how direction property control the UN-floating element**

> **Default** If `.container` direction is `ltr` and without `float` property `.left-column` and `.right-column`.

```css
* {
     -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    body{
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    .container {
      direction: ltr;
      padding: 5px;
     width: 400px;
     overflow: hidden;
     background: lightgreen;
    }
    .left-column {
     width: 50%;
     /*float: left; */ /* No float */
     background: red;
    }
    .right-column {
     width: 50%;
     /*float: left;*/ /* No float*/
     background: cyan;
    }
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='left-column'>I am the left column</div>
  <div class='right-column'>I am the right column</div>
</div>
```

> **Default** If `.container` direction is `ltr` and `float: left;` for `.left-column`.

```css
* {
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    body{
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    .container {
      direction: ltr;
      padding: 5px;
        width: 400px;
        overflow: hidden;
        background: lightgreen;
    }
    .left-column {
        width: 50%;
        float: left; /* float left */
        background: red;
    }
    .right-column {
        width: 50%;
        /*float: left;*/ /* No float*/
        background: cyan;
    }
```

```html
    <div class='container'>
  <div class='left-column'>I am the left column</div>
  <div class='right-column'>I am the right column</div>
</div>
```

**Note:** No change

> **Default** If `.container` direction is `ltr` and `float: left;` for `.left-column` and `.right-column`.

```css
* {
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    body{
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    .container {
      direction: ltr;
      padding: 5px;
        width: 400px;
        overflow: hidden;
        background: lightgreen;
    }
    .left-column {
        width: 50%;
        float: left; /* No float */
        background: red;
    }
    .right-column {
        width: 50%;
        float: left; /* No float*/
        background: cyan;
    }
```

```html
<div class='container'>
<div class='left-column'>I am the left column</div>
<div class='right-column'>I am the right column</div>
</div>
```

**Note:** Now it change box-model position.

> **Custom** If `.container` direction is `rtl` and without `float` property `.left-column` and `.right-column`.

```css
* {
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    body{
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    .container {
      direction: rtl;
      padding: 5px;
        width: 400px;
        overflow: hidden;
        background: lightgreen;
    }
    .left-column {
        width: 50%;
        /*float: left; */ /* No float */
        background: red;
    }
    .right-column {
        width: 50%;
        /*float: left;*/ /* No float*/
        background: cyan;
    }
```

```html
<div class='container'>
<div class='left-column'>I am the left column</div>
<div class='right-column'>I am the right column</div>
</div>
```

> You can play with like this.

**Only direction property controlled UN-floating element.**

Comment: My question is "why" not how to solve it. I already have the solution in the question.